# Boot tongue orientation?

Tags: boots

I recently bought a pair of Meindl Ohio winter boots.  I am generally happy with them, but I have noticed that, after a day of wearing the boots, the tongues of each boot tend to migrate outwards.

You can imagine this by thinking of the label on the tongue, with the brand logo on it. When I put the boots on, this logo is facing directly forwards.  After wearing the boots for awhile, I find that the tongue shifts so that these logos are facing outwards at about 45 degrees.

Does this indicate a poor fit?

Comment: Is there a little loop on the tongue?  I see the same issue with shoes and boots, but some have a loop for the last pass of the laces to pass through, which can keep them in place, or nearly so.

Comment: How do the boots feel though? Does this tongue migration cause discomfort, or do the boots remain comfortable? In other words, if you didn't look at the tongue, would you have even known the tongue had shifted? I had some shoes that did this and I quit worrying about it because they feel fine.

Comment: Out of curiosity - do you have high arches? I do, and it occurred to me that perhaps that's a contributing factor.

Answer (score 3):

This could indicate a poor fit, but if they boots are otherwise comfortable then I would not say it is due to a poor fit. It is very possible that as they break in more and more this problem will happen less and less.

If the boot tongue does not have loops to pass the laces through there is not a lot you can do. I would explore various lacing techniques that would put more friction on the tongue.

If you really love everything about the boot except this tongue slippage then maybe you can look into attached loops down the center of the tongue to help keep it in place.